# Pre-Añadir un div a otro determinado y tras esto al último elemento añadido

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

En este ejemplo necesito que al `div #fijo` se le añada antes con un `.preppend` el `div` que se haya seleccionado de la lista de "prefijados" y tras esto si seguimos añadiendo "prefijados" éstos se añadan antes del último prefijado y si des-seleccionamos todo que el proceso vuelva a empezar.

**Ejemplo**
Si hago `click` en Prefijado 2 : se añadirá el `div #prefijado2` antes de #fijo
Si hago `click` en Prefijado 3 : se añadirá el `div #prefijado3` antes de `#prefijado2`
Si des-selecciono todo: se retirarán los `divs` y volverá a añadirse cualquiera de los 3 antes de `#fijo`.

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0}
#container{width:100%; position:absolute; top:50px;}
#fijo{width:50%; height:100px; background:red; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado1{width:50%; height:100px; background:cyan; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado2{width:50%; height:100px; background:yellow; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado3{width:50%; height:100px; background:green; margin-left:25%;}
ul{display:table; position:fixed; text-align:center;}
il{display:table-cell;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Prefijado1 <input type="checkbox" id="pref1" value="prefijado1"></li>
    <li>Prefijado2 <input type="checkbox" id="pref2" value="prefijado2"></li>
    <li>Prefijado3 <input type="checkbox" id="pref3" value="prefijado3"></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fijo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si los id de los checkbox tienen id="prefijadoX", entonces no sería lógico agregar un `<div id="prefijadoX">`, al menos según la especificación.

Comment: Sí perdona @shaz fue un despiste al simplificar el código para la pregunta ahora mismo lo corrijo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El código JS realiza las siguientes acciones:

> - Al hacer **click** sobre cualquiera de los `checkbox`, si el mismo **esta `checked`**, agrega un `div` con `id` igual al `value` del `checkbox`. La ubicacion del mismo sera justo antes del `div#fijo` o, si contador fuera mayor a 0, antes del hermano anterior `n` al `div#fijo`. Al mismo tiempo incrementa el valor de la variable privada `contador` para guardar una referencia a la cantidad de elementos agregados.
> - Al hacer **click** sobre cualquiera de los `checkbox`, si el mismo **no esta `checked`**, elimina el `div` con `id` igual al `value` del `checkbox`. Luego decrementa el valor de la variable privada `contador` para actualizar la referencia a la cantidad de elementos agregados.

```js
(function() {
  var contador = 0;
  $fijo = $('#fijo');

  // Al hacer click en los checkboxs
  $('#container input').on('click', function() {
    var $check = $(this),
      id = $check.val(),
      $hermano = $fijo,
      $div;

    if ($check.prop('checked')) {
      $div = $('<div id="' + id + '">');

      // Agregamos contenido HTML al $div
      $div.html('<span>Texto aquí</span>');

      // Si ya agregamos, buscamos el "n" hermano anterior de #fijo o #fijo
      $hermano = contador ? $fijo.prevAll().eq(contador - 1) : $fijo;
      $div.insertBefore($hermano);
      contador++;
    } else {
      $('#' + id).remove();
      contador--;
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0}
#container{width:100%; position:absolute; top:50px;}
#fijo{width:50%; height:100px; background:red; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado1{width:50%; height:100px; background:cyan; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado2{width:50%; height:100px; background:yellow; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado3{width:50%; height:100px; background:green; margin-left:25%;}
ul{display:table; position:fixed; text-align:center;}
il{display:table-cell;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Prefijado1 <input type="checkbox" id="pref1" value="prefijado1"></li>
    <li>Prefijado2 <input type="checkbox" id="pref2" value="prefijado2"></li>
    <li>Prefijado3 <input type="checkbox" id="pref3" value="prefijado3"></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fijo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sería mucho mejor para el OP si añadieras una pequeña descripción de tu código.

Comment: He agregado una pequeña descripción de lo que hace el código JS

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos por la ayuda, la verdad es que es una repuesta impecable. Una última duda; ¿cómo haría si el div #prefijado2 no solo tuviese propiedades css sino también un <span> ? Gracias!

Comment: Fijate ahora, he agregado una linea donde le agrego contenido HTML al `$div` que se crea.

Comment: eres Dios... :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// buscamos los checkboxes    
var items = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var container = document.getElementById("container")
var ul = document.querySelector("ul")

// añadimos el evento de click
for (var i = 0, item=items[0]; i<items.length; ++i, item=items[i])
{
    item.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.checked ? insert(this.value) : remove(this.value);

    })

}

// la funcion insert
var insert = function( new_id )
{
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = new_id;
  ul.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ul.nextSibling)
}

// la funcion eliminar
var remove = function( id )
{
    var div = document.getElementById(id)
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0}
#container{width:100%; position:absolute; top:50px;}
#fijo{width:50%; height:100px; background:red; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado1{width:50%; height:100px; background:cyan; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado2{width:50%; height:100px; background:yellow; margin-left:25%;}
#prefijado3{width:50%; height:100px; background:green; margin-left:25%;}
ul{display:table; position:fixed; text-align:center;}
il{display:table-cell;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Prefijado1 <input type="checkbox" id="pref1" value="prefijado1"></li>
    <li>Prefijado2 <input type="checkbox" id="pref2" value="prefijado2"></li>
    <li>Prefijado3 <input type="checkbox" id="pref3" value="prefijado3"></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fijo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Por lo que entiendo, quieres ir añadiendo los divs antes que el div fijo, en el orden en el que se clican. En la pregunta dices que se utilice la funcion prepend. Prepend, por lo que yo tengo entendido, inserta un elemento al inicio del nodo especificado

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

pero tu lo que quieres es insertar nodos antes o despues de un nodo concreto, con lo cual te adjunto mi solución hecha en js puro.

El truco esta en la funcion insert encontrada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793604/how-to-do-insert-after-in-javascript-without-using-a-library)
Lo que hace es acceder al nodo padre del nodo referencia (para poder usar insert before), y lo coloca inmediatamente antes del siguiente hermano del nodo referencia. Lo que conlleva que lo situe despues del nodo referencia.

Aqui tienes el ejemplo completo funcionando [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hermetico/zegeezom/)